# Kafka - 1 or more partitions have more than configured number of replicas

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a Kafka topic which has 1 partition with more replicas than are configured for this topic;

```
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 0    Leader: 40038   Replicas: 40038,40027   Isr: 40038,40027
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 1    Leader: 40044   Replicas: 40044,40028   Isr: 40028,40044
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 2    Leader: 40030   Replicas: 40030,40026   Isr: 40030,40026
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 3    Leader: 40028   Replicas: 40028,40044   Isr: 40028,40044
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 4    Leader: 40036   Replicas: 40036,40037   Isr: 40036,40037
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 5    Leader: 40039   Replicas: 40039,40042   Isr: 40039,40042
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 6    Leader: 40015   Replicas: 40015,40031   Isr: 40015,40031
Topic: TopicA   Partition: 7    Leader: 40041   Replicas: 40041,40046,40038 Isr: 40038,40041
```

I believe this happened during a botched rebalance attempt for this topic, which got stuck/exited on this partition.

Is there some way to return this partition to the configured replication factor 2?

Comment: Looks like a situation KIP-550 is trying to address: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-550%3A+Mechanism+to+Delete+Stray+Partitions+on+Broker. Until its implemented, I'm afraid you're left with manual clean-up of ZK and local file system.